# SharepointOnlineCredentials whit MFA

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sharepoint

I'm doing a little development where I have to delete some files on the machine and then download files from a Sharepoint to replace the deleted files.
In this case, the Sharepoint site uses MFA and I am using the following:

```
Dim siteUrl As String = "https://name_company.sharepoint.com/sites/Training/"
        Dim authManager = New OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager()
        Dim ctx As ClientContext = authManager.GetWebLoginClientContext(siteUrl)
        Dim web As Web = ctx.Web
        ctx.Load(web, Function(w) w.Title)
        ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        Console.WriteLine("You have connected to {0} site, with Multi Factor Authentication enabled!!", web.Title)
```

So far everything is fine, but later with the ClientContext type object, I have to authenticate with the sharepoint credentials, but these are of the String type

```
ctx.Credentials = New SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securedPassword)
```

And that's where I'm stuck, how can I get the session password (without using a textbox, inputbox or other control) from the ClientContext object to be able to authenticate in the Sharepoint?

I hope you can guide me.

Thank you and regards.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using an App password to overcome the MFA.
Reference:
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/08/connect-sharepoint-online-powershell-using-mfa.html

This password will act as the same role as user password but won't require MFA procedure (dialogue popup).

```
 Private Shared Sub Main(ByVal args As String())
Dim SiteUrl As String = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/dev"
Dim pwd = "gnckrrjmdwvbywtr"
Dim username = "amos@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
Dim context As ClientContext = New ClientContext(SiteUrl)
Dim securestring As SecureString = New SecureString()
pwd.ToCharArray().ToList().ForEach(Function(s) securestring.AppendChar(s))
context.Credentials = New SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securestring)
Dim web = context.Web
context.Load(web)
context.ExecuteQuery()
Console.WriteLine($"web title: {web.Title}")
Console.ReadKey()
```

End Sub

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, just a question, is possible to get the password of email account in another way., In my case, I already tried this way, obtaining the user's data, but when trying to log-in, I don't know why it doesn't allow them to access and it sends them an error message, and they are Owners on the SP site. That is why I had to try the CSOM solution, since it is the only one that obtains the data and allows logging, but I don't know how to execute the credentials part, when I need to authenticate. I hope you understand me.

Comment: Can you clarify the errors you are getting and the operations in code that are failing?